# NetBeans 7.0 C/C++.... Why are my backslashes being triple-escaped? And what is OUTPUT_PATH?

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, escaping, command-line-arguments

I recently upgraded to NetBeans 7.0 from 6.9. Hmm.. a lot of usability improvements, but some that confuse me as well. For C & C++ projects, there are two in particular I haven't been able to figure out:

1.There is one default command line argument for all C & C++ projects: `"${OUTPUT_PATH}"` (see image below) . What is this exactly? And why are my programs unable to work when I remove it as an argument?

[image]

2.Why are the backslashes of in all my arguments escaped multiple times? My arguments are entered as so:

```
"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data_1.txt"
"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data_2.txt"
"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\output.txt"
```

...yet they come out like so (though the program functions correctly):

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on these issues?

Comment: argv[0] is the programs name, so the program's name must be the first argument in the command.  ${OUTPUT_PATH} is the name of your executable.  As far as the backslashes go, it seems to me Netbeans is helping you out by escaping them for you.  Does it work right if you don't escape them?